# Docker container gets killed

Tags: docker

I am running a docker container which is trying to access a port in another docker container. Both of these are running are configured together to run on the same network. But as soon as I start this container it gets killed and doesn't throw any error. There are no error logs. I also tried using docker inspect but couldn't find much. 
PS: I am a newbie docker user.

Comment: The container will only run as long as its PID 1, usually set by `ENTRYPOINT` in the dockerfile or `docker run <image> -- <command>`

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile and/or docker-compose file? Like @stacksonstacks says, each container requires at least one running process. This can be something as simple as ```sh``` or ```bash```.

Comment: ENTRYPOINT /configure.sh && bash

Answer (score 0):

Following from OP comment w/ `ENTRYPOINT`

```
 ENTRYPOINT /configure.sh && bash
```

Answer

Given your `ENTRYPOINT` the container will always exit since the process is bash. You need to have a continuously running process in the foreground for the container to stay running i.e. an application daemon.

Comment: Can u please provide some suggestions on how can I avoid this?

Comment: I don't know what application you are trying to run in your container so I can't tell you what to command to run. I can only provide you with what the conceptual answer is. You would have to post more info on what application you are running in the container.

Comment: Thanks but the thing is the conainer won’t exit if i run it without putting it in a network and I do have a continuous process running. Basically this is a kafka connect container . I am trying to put this container along with another container so that kafka connect can access ports of the pther container.

Comment: Can you post your docker-compose & Dockerfile? Remove any sensitive info

Comment: Also no you don't have a continuous process running in the foreground since you are running `configure.sh && bash` which is basically bash calling bash again given that ENTRYPOINT is invoking the sub command. "/bin/sh -c". See docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: If `configure.sh` runs the actual Kafka process then you don't need `&& bash` after it because it pushes the Kafka process to the background and runs bash which causes the container to immediately exit.